# WPF 4 : PropertyChanged not updating Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my ViewModel, I have a class "A" with a child property "B" that is also a custom class. Both classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged and B's PropertyChanged event is hooked up to fire A's PropertyChanged event (with the correct property name of "B").

I also have a DependencyProperty "DPB" on my ViewModel that is bound to B in code with a very simple binding (new Binding("A.B")).

Now I have three TextBoxes in my view:

- 1 bound to A.B.C (a property of B)
- 1 bound directly to A.B
- 1 bound to DPB

On first run, both A.B and the DPB textboxes show the correct value. But when I change the A.B.C textbox, only the A.B textBox is updated - the DPB textBox is not updated.

I have debugged through all of the PropertyChanged notifying code and they are all hit with the correct values passed.

The problem seems to be that the DependencyProperty (or it's binding) is not being updated when the PropertyChanged event is fired. Can anyone tell me why or how to change this behaviour?

thank you.

Comment: You may need to add a `Mode=TwoWay` to the binding. However, I'm not sure I understood correctly your question, could you add some code?

Comment: Would look so much better if you build the class structure a little and paste it's code here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have bad news for you.

Inside `DependencyObject.SetValue` the check is located, which verify if new value equals to old value. So if you are binded to `A.B`, and changing of `A.B.C` produces PropertyChanged event for `A.B`, `Binding` mechanizm will handle this event and even call `DependencyObject.SetValue`. But then (due to equality of old and new `A.B` values) no changes will be applied to DP.

In order to achieve correct DP fireing, you should create new instance of A.B, that concludes in great headache.

**UPDATED**

You could use Freezable object, which supports notification that it has changed when its property is changed. DependencyObject works with Freezables correctly, so next example does what you need.

Model classes:

```
public class A 
{
    public A()
    {
        this.B = new B();
    }
    public B B
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}

public class B : Freezable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new B();
    }

    private string _c = "initial string";
    public string C
    {
        get
        {
            return _c;
        }
        set
        {
            this._c = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("C");
            this.OnChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var safe = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (safe != null)
        {
            safe(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding A.B.C}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty.C}" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class TextBoxesView : UserControl
{
    public TextBoxesView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.A = new A();
        this.DataContext = this;

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, TextBoxesView.MyPropertyProperty, new Binding("A.B"));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.A.B.C = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    public A A
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public B MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (B)this.GetValue(TextBoxesView.MyPropertyProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(TextBoxesView.MyPropertyProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty",
            typeof(B),
            typeof(TextBoxesView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, (d, e) => {  }));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that. Do you know how the check for equality is performed? If I override the equals and gethash methods, would it update?

Comment: Equals/GetHash method won't help because the object remains the same. Actually I don't know your purposes, and I can't advise to you. If I were you, I would think that such troubles are occured because of bad design. Also you could try to use Freezable. I've added some explaining code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and especially for the Freezable suggestion, I'm looking into that now. I agree that it's somewhat of a design issue, but it is being used where the B class type is not known at designtime, hence the need for an in-between property. I appreciate your help and will mark this answered soon.

Comment: After looking into Freezable, i can see how it could possibly be used but only with a lot of overhead. But your answer was correct in that DPs can not be forced to update on a PropertyChanged notification. Thanks.